# Xampp installation

Tags: installation, python, xampp

I get some troubles when I want to install the xampp tool, I run the command

```
sudo apt-get install xampp
```

and this is what I get in return

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
xampp:i386 : Depends: python-gtk2:i386 but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: python-glade2:i386 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Im using linux mint maya cinnamon

Comment: hate to be the tiniest bit elitist, but you could, and should just install the lamp stack with tasksel, then install phpmyadmin and a ftp server. It'll likely have newer versions. Apparently XAMPP needs a pair of GTK files its refusing to install. What's your architecture?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I'm pretty sure that's the standard way to do in the Debian/Ubuntu world. Anything else and you would be installing apache packages/modules one by one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well it worked with just an update of the software, and made it work downloading from the page the .tar file and executed it from terminal. It finally works :)

http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-linux.html

just check when executing that the command you enter, and the folder where it's saved matches every letter even caps...